# APEX trigger create record on Object_A from Object_B and update related list on Object_B

Tags: apex, related-list

As indicated in the title here is my scenario:

**I am still new to SF/Apex, and I think this is simple, but I'm struggling.

I have an Opportunity Object and that has a related list of Support Contracts.  I have a trigger that will create a new Project from the Opportunity when a user checks a box.  But what I also need it to do is update the related list of Support Contracts with the newly created Project name.

Here is what I have so far-- I have played around with Map and List, but I'm not getting anywhere.

Thank you!

```
trigger project_from_opportunity on Opportunity (before update)  { 
List<pse__Proj__c> projectList = new List<pse__Proj__c>();
List<pse__Budget__c> budgetList = new List<pse__Budget__c>();


List<Support_Contract__c> oppsWithServiceContract = new List<Support_Contract__c>([
   SELECT Id, Opportunity__c, Opportunity__r.Name, Product__c, Product_ID__r.pse__IsServicesProduct__c FROM Support_Contract__c
   WHERE (Opportunity__c !=null) AND (Opportunity__c IN :trigger.newMap.keySet()) ]);

FOR(Opportunity opp : Trigger.New){

    IF(Trigger.isUpdate){
    Opportunity oldopp = Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.id);
        IF(opp.Create_Project__c == true && oldopp.Create_Project__c == false && oppsWithServiceContract.size()>0){
            projectList.add(new  pse__Proj__c(
            Name = opp.ShortOppName__c + ' ' + opp.Account_Number__c + 'QQQ21'
            ,pse__Account__c = opp.AccountId
            ,pse__Is_Active__c = true
            ,pse__Is_Billable__c = true
            ,CurrencyIsoCode = opp.CurrencyIsoCode
            ,pse__End_Date__c = opp.PSA_Project_End_Date__c
            ,Internal_Notes__c = opp.Comments__c
            ,pse__Opportunity__c = opp.Id
            ,pse__Opportunity_Owner__c = opp.OwnerId
            ,pse__Practice__c = 'a20360000016A7d'
            ,Primary_Sales_Engineer__c = opp.Primary_Sales_Engineer__c
            ,Solutioning_DM__c = opp.Solutioning_DM__r.Name
            ,pse__Project_Status__c = 'Green'
            ,pse__Project_Type__c = 'RMA'
            ,Sales_Engineers__c = opp.Sales_Engineers__c
            ,SRC_Solutioning_Notes__c = opp.SRC_Solutioning_Notes__c
            ,pse__Stage__c = 'Provisional'
            ,pse__Start_Date__c = opp.CloseDate
            //,Order_Type__c = opp.SBQQ__PrimaryQuote__r.
            //,Payment_Terms__c = oppsWithPrimaryQuote.get(opp.Id).Quote__r[0].Payment_Terms__c
            ,Quote__c = opp.SBQQ__PrimaryQuote__r.Name
            ,Opportunity_Record_Type__c = opp.RecordTypeId
            ));
        IF(projectList.size()>0){
            Insert projectList;
        }

        //Because all dependencies are on the Project List the Budget is created without any verification
            budgetList.add(new pse__Budget__c(
            Name = opp.Name
            ,pse__Amount__c = 0.00
            ,pse__Project__c = projectList[0].id
            ,pse__Opportunity__c = projectList[0].pse__Opportunity__c
            ,pse__Account__c = projectList[0].pse__Account__c
            ,pse__Type__c = 'Customer Purchase Order'
            ,pse__Effective_Date__c = projectList[0].pse__Start_Date__c
            ,pse__Status__c = 'Approved'
            ,pse__Approved__c = true
            ,pse__Include_In_Financials__c = true));

            Insert budgetList;

//I am not sure what to do here....

            FOR( Support_Contract__c opps : oppsWithServiceContract ){
                //Delivery Milestones
                supportContractList.add(new Support_Contract__c(
                id = opps.id

                ));

                Upsert supportContractList;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally, if you want to do operations on other objects, you should use after trigger. See this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/254752/why-do-we-need-to-update-related-records-in-an-after-trigger-but-not-before).

Also best practice is to have only one trigger per object, and put your logic into Apex class(es). For example:

```java
trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (
    before insert, before update, after insert, after update, before delete, after undelete) {

    if (trigger.isBefore) {
         if (trigger.isInsert) {
         }
         else if (trigger.isUpdate) {
         }
         if (trigger.isDelete) {
         }
    }
    else if (trigger.isAfter) {
         if (trigger.isInsert) {
         }
         else if (trigger.isUpdate) {
            OpportunityClass.onUpdate(trigger.oldMap, trigger.newMap);
         }
         if (trigger.isUndelete) {
         }
    }
}
```

Then your OpportunityClass would be something like this:

```java
public class OpportunityClass {
    public static void onUpdate(Map<Id, Opportunity> oldMap, Map<Id, Opportunity> newMap) {
        // codes...
    }

}
```

Now, to your question:

> I have a trigger that will create a new Project from the Opportunity
>   when a user checks a box. But what I also need it to do is update the
>   related list of Support Contracts with the newly created Project name.

You might want to consider breaking your logic into two parts:

1. Opportunity Trigger, on after update, insert the Project record
2. Project Trigger, on after insert, upsert the Support Contracts

Then Project trigger would be something like this:

```java
trigger ProjectTrigger on pse__Proj__c (after insert) {

    if (trigger.isAfter && trigger.isInsert) {
        // Note: this whole thing below should be in an Apex class instead

        // collect the list of Opportunity IDs
        Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (pse__Proj__c p : trigger.new) {
            oppIds.add(p.pse__Opportunity__c);
        }
        oppIds.remove(null);

        // only perform if OppIds is not empty
        if (!oppIds.isEmpty()) {

            // query the opportunities with their Support Contracts
            // use child relationship query to get the Support Contracts
            // I assume the child relationship name is Support_Contracts
            Map<Id, Opportunity> oppWithSupportContracts = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([
                SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Support_Contracts__r) 
                FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :oppIds]);

            List<Support_Contract__c> supportContractsToUpdate = new List<Support_Contract__c>();
            for (pse__Proj__c p : trigger.new) {
                if (oppWithSupportContracts.containsKey(p.pse__Opportunity__c)) {
                    List<Support_Contract__c> supportContracts = 
                        oppWithSupportContracts.get(p.pse__Opportunity__c).Support_Contracts__r;
                    if (supportContracts.isEmpty()) {
                        // create a new Support Contract if there isn't one
                        supportContractsToUpdate.add(
                            new Support_Contract__c(
                                // assign the fields name value here
                                // sc.Opportunity__c = p.pse__Opportunity__c;
                                // sc.field1 = p.field1;
                                // sc.field2 = p.field2;
                                // ...
                            )
                        );
                    }
                    else {
                        // update existing Support Contracts
                        for (Support_Contract__c sc : supportContracts) {
                            // assign the fields name value here
                            // sc.field1 = p.field1;
                            // sc.field2 = p.field2;
                        }
                        supportContractsToUpdate.addAll(supportContracts);
                    }
                }
            }
            upsert(supportContractsToUpdate);
        }

    }
}
```

Please note that there are some violations in your code against Apex coding best practice, eg: SOQL and DML inside a loop. See [Apex Coding Best Practise](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices).

Answer (score 0):

I would say try something like this in your trigger code:

```
    trigger project_from_opportunity  on Opportunity (before update, before insert) {

    if(Trigger.isAfter || Trigger.isUpdate){
        for(Support_Contract__c sp : [Select Id,Name,(Select Id,Name From pse__Proj__r) From Support_Contract__c Where Opportunity__c in :Trigger.newMap.keySet()]){

            //Logic on the Support_Contract__c 'sp'  goes here...

            for(pse__Proj__c  psecontract : sp.pse__Proj__r){
                //Logic on the current child pse__Proj__c  psecontract  goes here...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

something similar to this:  https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000005H2SIAU